# Retrieve data in listview from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm beginner in android  and i don't now how populate  listview from method  DBHelper class  have same method working with static query and  i need make dinnamyc request inserting value into query from editext.

```
public void SrchDB(View v) {
  ListView p = (ListView) mDBHelper.findProduct(EdtxPoliza.getText().toString());
  if (p == null)
  {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No Match Found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that you want `findProduct` to return a ListView object. Maybe you meant for an Arraylist? In any case, you shouldn't look into the documentation for the CursorAdapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Modify your `mDBHelper.findProduct(String);` to return `Collection`, say `ArrayList<String>`

```
public ArrayList<String> findProduct(String vString){
   SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
   ArrayList<String> myRes = new ArrayList<>();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("YOUR_QUERY", null);
   while (cursor.moveToNext()){
       myRes.add(cursor.getString(0)); //change the index to your column index in table.
   }
   return myRes;
}
```

**Second**

Create Adapter

```
ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ResultOf_findProduct);
```

**Third**

set Adapter to `yourListView`

```
yourListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

That's it, hope it will help you.

Comment: Thankful for your help iSandeep
It's already solved

Comment: @EDenebd If it's a correct answer then mark it.